# cocoon, link_to_remove_association with confirm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cocoon-gem

is there an easy way to add confirm dialog box that would appear when user clicks link_to_remove_association ?

cocoon gem is really great, I wonder if it has such a ready option ?? if not, can I use jQuery to cancel or let go the event ?

Thanks,

Comment: Nice question. I haven't needed that myself, since you are editing a form, which still needs to be saved before changes take effect, so I always assume that if a user removes a nested element by mistake, she or he can still just press cancel or reload the page. But I will try to answer your question :)

Comment: I agree that this is necessary. We can't and shouldn't expect our end users to understand that hitting "Remove Item" isn't permanent. Good UI design dictates that we warn them about the deletion, even if the change isn't submitted to the server.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to simply `<%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure that you want to remove these nested fields?' } %>`, no?

Comment: no, i dont think so, read what the author said at the question comment

Comment: I am doing this in my view. The only thing that I am unclear about would be the event where "user removes a nested element by mistake". The confirm dialog applies when the "user clicks the remove link by mistake". But if the element is removed, then it is removed. An "undo" function is a separate issue altogether.

Comment: Nope, this is precisely the way you should do this. I just never tried that before, because as explained: I do not see the use of this. All options given to `link_to_remove_association` are just handed to `link_to` (and I just tested and confirmed this works). If a user makes a mistake, he can always reload the page or go back. Changes only take effect when the user submits the form.

Comment: This is almost correct. The confirm hash needs to be nested under a `data` dash: look at the answer from @kostafun for the correct method.

Comment: The element will be remove nontheless. I suppose this is tied to the click event which is still propagated.

Answer (score 3):

```
  = link_to_remove_association "remove item", f,  data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```

tested working :)

Answer (score 1):

I added a click handler to the remove-link and prevented the event from propagating by returning false..

```
$(".container").on('click',"a.remove_fields",function(){
  return confirm("Do you want to delete this?") ;
});
```